# grep using grep results

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have two files containing attribute names and properties, where  different data is stored in two files:

**1.txt:**

```
abc12      3@     50
edf13      4@     50
dde8       3@     50
```

**2.txt**

```
abc12      3@     65
edf13      4@     50
dde8       3@     70
dde7       3@     70
```

I want to grep as follows: 
first- `grep "3@" 1.txt | awk '{print $1}'`, then `grep * 2.txt` where star(*) represent output of first grep.

all should be done in a single line from the prompt.

**expected output:**

```
abc12      3@     65
dde8       3@     70
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: `join <(grep 3@ 1.txt | sort) <(grep 3@ 2.txt | sort) -o 1.1,1.2,2.3 | column -t`

Answer (score 4):

With one `awk` process:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if ($2 ~ "3@") a[$1]++; next} a[$1]' 1.txt 2.txt
```

the first `condition{action}` means when reading from first file, increase the array element with this first field as hash. The second condition `a[$1]` is true when this element is one or more, this is checked for the second file and the default action is to print the line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are better, this is if you insist on `grep`:

```
grep "3@" 1.txt| awk '{print $1}' | while read i;do grep $i 2.txt;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with join and grep

```
join -t $'\t' -o 2.1 2.2 2.3 1.txt 2.txt | grep 3@
```