# pipe'd grep: grep on result of another grep

Tags: grep

Q: How do I pipe multi-results of first search to search a second file.

Ex:

```
1) FILE1
system abc{
system ghi{
....
...

2) FILE2
define ABC_1_SUFFIX  0XF67
define ABC_2_SUFFIX  0XF34
define DEF_1_SUFFIX  0XF65
define DEF_2_SUFFIX  0XF11
define GHI_1_SUFFIX  0XF73
define GHI_2_SUFFIX  0XF82  


grep -r "^system" file | awk '{print $2}'   
grep -r "#define.*<result of 1st grep>" file2
```

Task: How do I pass result of first grep (which is abc,def,ghi against grep -r "^system" ) inside second grep. I know pipe/xargs but cant figure this out yet.

I did search related topic but solution didnt work out.
1] [GREP by result of awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521290/grep-by-result-of-awk)
2] [grep using grep results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854252/grep-using-grep-results)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Are you expecting multiline output from the first grep and want to match each?  It feels like you want `xargs`, but it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, yes .. so the second grep is like grep'ing over loop of results of first. I have not used xargs in a grep on a file, could you please let me know how I can use same. Thanks for your hints

Comment: Sorry, it's still not at all clear what you want.  From the sample files you've shown, it seems like the solution you are looking for is `cat FILE2`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I removed  "system def{" from FILE1. Now, the result should be all address related to abc and ghi only, omitting def. A script will work it but trying for a one liner hack. Pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not really clear exactly what you want, but perhaps something like:

```
$ cat file1
system abc{
system ghi{
$ cat file2
define ABC_1_SUFFIX  0XF67
define ABC_2_SUFFIX  0XF34
define DEF_1_SUFFIX  0XF65
define DEF_2_SUFFIX  0XF11
define GHI_1_SUFFIX  0XF73
define GHI_2_SUFFIX  0XF82
$ awk '/^system/ && NR==FNR { gsub("[^a-zA-Z]","",$2); 
    a[toupper($2)] = 1; next } 
    /^define/ {for(k in a) if(match($0,k)) print $3}' file1 file2
0XF67
0XF34
0XF73
0XF82
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want! Appreciate it, sorry if I wasnt exaclty clear with my Q but I guess you have the answer neverthless :)

Comment: It's probably easier to preproces file1 into a file of patterns to match and use 'grep -i -f ...'

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean passing the first command's output to the second command itself?

Maybe something like this?

```sh
fisrt="$(grep -r "^system" file)"
second="$(grep -r "#define.*${first}" file2)"
```

Ugly one-liner:

```
grep -r "#define.*$(grep -r "^system" file)" file2
```

Comment: Thx for the edit, @William Pursell, that's what I meant

Comment: grep -ri "#define.*grep -r '^system.*{' FILE1| awk '{print $2}'"  FILE2 
didnt work for the above files